# sql cost to avg cost of all missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> SELECT CONCERTS.TYPEOFCONCERT, CONCERTS.COSTOFEACHCONCERT
  2  FROM CUSTOMER
  3  INNER JOIN BOOKING
  4  ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
  5  INNER JOIN EVENT
  6  ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
  7  INNER JOIN CONCERTS
  8  ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID
  9  (
 10  SELECT AVG(COSTOFEACHCONCERT) FROM CONCERTS AS TOTALCOSTOFCONCERTS
 11  );
SELECT AVG(COSTOFEACHCONCERT) FROM CONCERTS AS TOTALCOSTOFCONCERTS
*
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I am getting an error when trying to find out the avg cost of all concerts and showing the difference between the cost and avg cost of all concerts. can someone let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: what mean the code in line 9 , 10 2 11 ?  .. (
 SELECT AVG(COSTOFEACHCONCERT) FROM CONCERTS AS TOTALCOSTOFCONCERTS  )   this code is in wrong place .. you should remove it

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your last post, you are confused about how to use grouping functions. Try the following:

```
SELECT CONCERTS.TYPEOFCONCERT, CONCERTS.COSTOFEACHCONCERT, 
(SELECT AVG(COSTOFEACHCONCERT) FROM CONCERTS) AS AVERAGECOSTOFCONCERTS,
(SELECT SUM(COSTOFEACHCONCERT) FROM CONCERTS) AS TOTALCOSTOFCONCERTS
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKING.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN EVENT ON EVENT.EVENTID=BOOKING.EVENTID
INNER JOIN CONCERTS ON CONCERTS.CONCERTID=EVENT.CONCERTID
```

This uses two subqueries in the select clause. Your result will be each type of concert, the cost, and the constants average cost of all concerts and total cost of all concerts. I used both of those because your description didn't really match your SQL statement, so I was confused as to what you were actually after.

Anyway, those subqueries perform their own select statement that returns a 1x1 table and thus repeats the value for every row selected. It is not the most efficient code, so beware if you try to use it for thousands of rows.